# How to add autotrack to a React App

Tags: create-react-app

Does anyone know how to add [autotrack](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack) to a React app built with [Create-React-App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) by loading autotrack via npm and then include it in my build by importing it?